# How to use ImageMagick to put background under animated, rendered foreground

Tags: image, background, imagemagick, transparent, animated-gif

I have some rendered, animated planets with a transparent background (checkered in most viewers) and want to put a background star field behind them, like this:

[image: Planet over Stars]

I'm currently rendering a flat plane behind the image with the star jpeg mapped as a texture but that's got problems I want to avoid. I don't want an object back there, I just want a static background (an actual object causes complexity with shadows, camera angles, lighting etc)

I'm trying various ImageMagic commands like this but nothing seems to work. They either kill the animation entirely (make it a still image) or flash the background once per cycle of the animation and display the checkered background for the remaining frames.

```
convert animated_planet.gif stars2.jpg -composite planet_with_background.gif
```

[image: animated with transparent background]

[image: Background I want under every frame]

Answer (score 0):

Post your foreground and background images. In Imagemagick, you can put a constant background under an animation that has transparency as follows assuming Imagemagick 6.

```
convert animation.gif -coalesce null: background.suffix -compose dstOver -layers composite -layers optimize new_animation.gif
```

where suffix is your background image suffix (JPG, PNG, GIF etc)

If on Imagemagick 7, replace `convert` with `magick`

See

https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/#background

**ADDITION:**

This works fine for me on IM 6.9.12-49 Q16 Mac OSX Monterey.

```
convert animation.gif -coalesce null: background.jpg -compose dstOver -layers composite -layers optimize new_animation.gif
```

[image]

Or if you want to slow it down a bit:

```
convert -delay 20 animation.gif -coalesce null: background.jpg -compose dstOver -layers composite -layers optimize -loop 0 new_animation2.gif
```

[image]

Comment: That sort of works -layer option has to be -layers, however it only puts a background on the first frame. In subsequent frames any moving object leaves a trail. I'll post the animated gif and background

Comment: Typo on the second -layers.  Let me test and check the -dispose option. I do not see your result?

Comment: It works fine for me. See my ADDITION in my answer above.

Comment: Yeah, maybe my transparent animated gif is already messed up before getting to the background addition stage. The "moons" should not be leaving a trail in the transparent gif. Let me try the latest additions...

Comment: Your original animation (or at least the version you posted or got uploaded) has a trail of moons. Is that what is the issue? If so, it is already in your transparent original animation.

Comment: I have it rotating nice and slow in the final product it's just that I could not upload the pre-optimized file for you to see because stack limits uploads to less than 2meg.

Comment: If it is still an issue, then zip the file. That may reduce the size. And/or upload to some free hosting service and put the link here. I can then review your actual original.

Comment: Got it! It was the -dispose option. Thanks for getting me rolling again.

nice convert -delay ${DELAY} -dispose Background *.png -coalesce null: ../../backgrounds/stars2.jpg -compose dstOver -layers composite -layers optimize -loop 0 planet.gif